# How can I add percentages into my table using SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of `Sign_Ups_with_Want_Created` out of `Sign_Ups` in the query below. I thought I would just be able to add a line of code dividing sign_ups_with_want_created / sign_ups within the query but I get this error when I run the query:

> Syntax error line 8:1: Column 'sign_ups_with_want_created' cannot be resolved

Code:

```
select
    month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month,
    count(distinct u.id) as Sign_Ups,
    count (distinct w.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Want_Created,
    count(distinct g.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Reel_Created,
    count(distinct 
             case 
                when g.status = 'done' then g.owner 
             end) as Sign_Ups_with_Done_Reel,
   count(distinct 
             case 
                when g.status = 'active' then g.owner 
             end) as Sign_Ups_with_Active_Reel
from
    prodjoinreel.users u
left join 
    prodjoinreel.goals g on g.owner = u.id
left join 
    prodjoinreel.wants w on w.owner = u.id
where 
    year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
group by 
    Month
order by 
    Month
```

Thank you

Comment: "column cannot be resolved" sounds like Presto/Athena - not SQL Server

Comment: Is there really a space in the second count()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is SQL Server based on the error message, but one way to try to accomplish this is to use the column calculations again in the percentage formula. Depending on the actual engine you're using, you might need to `cast()` the `count()` results to decimal in order to retain the precision of the division.

I've used T-SQL syntax:

```
select
  month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month,
  count(distinct u.id) as Sign_Ups,
  count (distinct w.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Want_Created,
  count(distinct g.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Reel_Created,
                count(distinct 
                    case 
                    when g.status = 'done' then g.owner 
                    end
                ) as Sign_Ups_with_Done_Reel,
   count(distinct 
                    case 
                    when g.status = 'active' then g.owner 
                    end
                ) as Sign_Ups_with_Active_Reel,
   /* sign_ups_with_want_created / sign_ups */
   cast(cast(count(distinct w.owner) as decimal(19,4)) / cast(count(distinct u.id) as decimal(19,4)) as decimal(19,4)) as Pct_Sign_Ups_with_Want_Created
from
  prodjoinreel.users u
  left join prodjoinreel.goals g on g.owner = u.id
left join prodjoinreel.wants w on w.owner = u.id
where year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
group by Month
order by Month
```

The above is straightforward but is harder to maintain, essentially copying code. In SQL Server, there are other options.

Another solution would be to use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), calculating the percentage from the temporary result set.

Yet another solution would be to select the initial results into a temp table; use the temp table to get the final results; and drop the temp table.

Comment: I doubt your example will work any better with the space in the second count function. The error is "Column 'sign_ups_with_want_created' cannot be resolved"

Comment: @JoeDBAHAHAHA -- That might be a limitation in Presto/Athena (idk), but the extra space is legal in T-SQL. I _think_ the OP was trying to use the aliased column in the percentage calculation, which is illegal syntax. `select count (*) from sys.tables` is equivalent to `select count(*) from sys.tables`.